# Estoy haciendo un interrumptor que al tocar cada una de las teclas se prende o se apaga una "luz". La funcionalidad está, pero me aparece el error ->>

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 HTML: 

<div class="container__antoher-buttons">

        <div class="container__luz">

            <div class="luz"></div>

        </div>    

        <button type="button" class="button button--on">On</button>

        <button type="button" class="button button--off">Off</button>

      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container__antoher-buttons {
margin: 5rem;
padding: 1rem;
}

.button {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: .3rem;
padding: 1rem;
border: .1rem solid #000000;
background-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.button--off:hover {
background-color: #ff000064;
}

.button--on:hover {
background-color: #00ff2664;
 }

.container__luz {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
border: .1rem solid #000000;
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.luz--colorVerde {
width: 1.5rem;
height: 1.5rem;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 38);
}

.luz--colorRojo {
width: 1.5rem;
height: 1.5rem;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const botonOn = document.querySelector('.button--on');

const botonOff = document.querySelector('.button--off');

const luzColor = document.querySelector('.luz');

botonOn.addEventListener('click', function () {
const luzVerde = document.createElement('div')
luzVerde.classList.add('luz--colorVerde')
luzColor.appendChild(luzVerde)
botonOff.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const borrarLuzVerde = document.querySelector('.luz--colorVerde');
    borrarLuzVerde.remove(borrarLuzVerde);
})
})

botonOff.addEventListener('click', function () {
const luzRoja = document.createElement('div')
luzRoja.classList.add('luz--colorRojo')
luzColor.appendChild(luzRoja)
botonOn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const borrarLuzRoja = document.querySelector('.luz--colorRojo');
    borrarLuzRoja.remove(borrarLuzRoja);
})
})
```

ERROR EN CONSOLA:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (interruptor.js:29:24)
```

La funcionalidad en el botón está, es decir, cuando yo presiono "ON" la "luz" se torna verde, y cuando presiono "OFF" la luz se pone roja. Hay algunos detalles como por ejemplo que cuando vuelvo a presionar la luz verde seguido de haberla presionado agrega una más y no debería.

Me imagino que el error debe estar en que al tocar el botón "crea y borra" el elemento al mismo tiempo, pero no se como solucionarlo. Disculpen el lío, soy principiante en JS.

Espero sus respuestas, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas borrar el html cada vez que presionas los botones.  Ademas no hay necesidad de agregar 2 handlers para cada boton.

```js
const botonOn = document.querySelector('.button--on');

const botonOff = document.querySelector('.button--off');

const luzColor = document.querySelector('.luz');

botonOn.addEventListener('click', function () {
const luzVerde = document.createElement('div')
luzVerde.classList.add('luz--colorVerde')
luzColor.innerHTML = "";
luzColor.appendChild(luzVerde)

})

botonOff.addEventListener('click', function () {
const luzRoja = document.createElement('div')
luzRoja.classList.add('luz--colorRojo')
luzColor.innerHTML = "";
luzColor.appendChild(luzRoja)

})
```

```css
.container__antoher-buttons {
margin: 5rem;
padding: 1rem;
}

.button {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: .3rem;
padding: 1rem;
border: .1rem solid #000000;
background-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.button--off:hover {
background-color: #ff000064;
}

.button--on:hover {
background-color: #00ff2664;
 }

.container__luz {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
border: .1rem solid #000000;
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.luz--colorVerde {
width: 1.5rem;
height: 1.5rem;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 38);
}

.luz--colorRojo {
width: 1.5rem;
height: 1.5rem;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__antoher-buttons">

        <div class="container__luz">

            <div class="luz"></div>

        </div>    

        <button type="button" class="button button--on">On</button>

        <button type="button" class="button button--off">Off</button>

      </div>
```